# Python OOP object printing properties problem

Tags: python, list, function, oop, printing

So I am working on a card game when I try to form a Pile class where I constructed a function to print the card in the card class and a list of cards in the pile class. When I try to use the function from the card class (that worked in other classes) in the pile class I don't get the expected result. How can I fix this?

Card Class:

```
import random
from Enums import *

class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.suit = Suit.find(random.randint(1, 4))
        self.rank = Rank.find(random.randint(1, 14))

    def show(self):
        print (self.rank.value[1], "of", self.suit.value[1])
```

Pile Class:

```
from Enums import *
from Card import *
from Hand import *

class Pile:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.cards.append(Card())

    def discard(self, hand, card):
        self.cards.append(card)

        if (not searchCard(self, hand, card)):
            print ("The card was not found, please select another one or cheat")
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def takePile(self, hand):
        for x in self.cards:
            hand.cards.append(self.cards[x])

    def clearPile(self):
        while len(self.cards) > 0:
            self.cards.pop()

    def searchCard(self, hand, card):
        flag = False

        for x in hand.cards and not flag:
            if (hand.cards[x].rank.value[0] == card.rank.value[0]):
                if (hand.cards[x].suit.value[0] == card.suit.value[0]):
                    hand.cards[x].pop()
                    flag = True

        return flag

    def showCurrent(self):
        for x in self.cards:
            x.show()
```

I am referring to the show function on the Card class and the showCurrent and init in the Pile class

When I run the game and the line

```
print ("It's your turn now, the pile presents a", pile.showCurrent())
```

I get a None instead of a print from the show function in the Card class as follows:

It's your turn now, the pile presents a None

Comment: Well, you are printing the result of `showCurrent()`, which is `None`. Just call `showCurrent` _after_ the `print`, then it should work as expected.

Comment: Can you show an answer with an __str__ function instead?

Comment: Also, from the printed message, it appears that `showCurrent` should only print the top-most card, but it will print all the cards.

Comment: But I use the show function too so it has to use it and print what goes there

Comment: The question is: Do you want any of the `show` functions to print something out themselves, or should they return something that another entity prints?

Comment: I found the issue and fixed the problem, thanks tobias_k

Comment: Please update the question with the source of the problem and you fix. This may be useful for someone else in the future.

Comment: In general, keep I/O has close to the "edge" of your program as possible. If you have a choice between printing something now and returning a string for someone *else* to print, prefer the latter.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you are printing the result of `showCurrent()`, which is `None`. To fix this, just move the call to `showCurrent` out of the `print`:

```
print("It's your turn now, the pile presents a")
pile.showCurrent()
```

Also, you might want to change your `show` method to a proper `__str__` method to make it more versatile. You will have to change your `showCurrent` method, too:

```
# in class Card:
def __str__(self): # just return the formatted string here
    return "%s of %s" % (self.rank.value[1], self.suit.value[1])

# in class Pile:
def showCurrent(self): # print the string here
    for x in self.cards:
        print(x) # this calls str(x), which calls x.__str__()
```

But your message suggests that you actually just want to print the top-most card, not the entire stack. With `__str__` you can now do this directly in the `print` call:

```
print("It's your turn now, the pile presents a", pile.cards[0]) # calls __str__
```

Comment: You probably want to use `%s`, not `%r`, in `__str__`.

Comment: @chepner Right, fixed.